# Achieving a Clean Wireframe Effect on Complex Models in Blender

Tags: modeling, wireframe

I'm new to Blender and I'm trying to achieve a specific look for an object. I want the object to have an outline or wireframe appearance, like in the image below.

I've looked into the Wireframe Modifier, and it works well on a basic cube. However, when I try it on the car model I'm working on, it looks quite messy! I know it might be possible to achieve this effect using materials, but I'd like to try having the object as just the wireframe first.Is there a technique or method I can use to achieve the result I want?

I apologize for my grammar; English is not my native language. I hope I've expressed my issue clearly!

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about deleting all the edges, that you don't want?

Comment: are the two images reall the same model? Maybe provide a blendfile using https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Maybe use a method or addon that will create an outline? Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kUzQ2u1xq2Q

Comment: i think the wireframe modifier is your best bet. Maybe you need to cleanup your original model for best results, and play with the modifiers settings

Comment: @maddes8cht I don't think they are the same model as it is stated nowhere, I guess that's just an example for the desired look...

Comment: @ Leander  @ maddes8cht
Thank you for your responses. I have considered the need for cleaning up the original model, but simplifying the model is a rather tedious task. Therefore, before starting again, I wanted to ask if there are any faster methods available.

Comment: @moonboots
Thank you for your suggestion. I will try to process the model first, and if it doesn't yield the desired results, I will then attempt the steps for the video. Thank you!

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann
Yes, this is an example used to represent the effect I want to achieve.